# Gatsby navigation with query parameters do hard refresh and lose the parameters

Tags: reactjs, navigation, gatsby, reach-router

I have private pages behind a login page, if you try to reach a page the first you'll face is a redirect to the Login page and once you're logged successfully you will be redirected to the page you ask for, for example.

```
https://example.com/one-of-the-private-pages
```

redirect to

```
https://example.com/login
```

then redirect to

```
https://example.com/one-of-the-private-pages
```

the redirect is with the navigate utils from Gatsby

All this Logic is working as expected but the problem is when I need query parameters

```
https://example.com/one-of-the-private-pages?param1='example'
```

In this case, the behavior is:

- Redirect to the Login page

After login

```
navigate(https://example.com/one-of-the-private-pages?param1='example')
```

then I can see a blink in the page with the parameter and a hard refresh
Finally, my URL is:

```
https://example.com/one-of-the-private-pages
```

This only happens after building to production in development mode everything works as respected

Note: I try deleting all the content on the page actually only has a div and an h1 component.

Answer (score 4):

Gatsby, extends from `@reach/router` (from React) so it follows [the behavior of it](https://reach.tech/router/nesting). It's intended to use only for internal navigation and, by default, does not support hashed URLs nor parameters, as the [docs points](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-link/):

> Neither `<Link>` nor `navigate` can be used for in-route navigation with a
> hash or query parameter. If you need this behavior, you should either
> use an anchor tag or import the `@reach/router` package—which Gatsby
> already depends upon—to make use of its `navigate` function, like so:

That's why your page blinks before losing the parameters. Don't focus on the `gatsby develop`/`gatsby build`, they have different behaviors, treat and compile the code differently and, that doesn't mean that your code has something wrong and it has stopped working in one environment, it's just that Gatsby doesn't support it.

Said that, at this point, you have two options:

- Use the `@reach/router` dependency directly, as the documentation suggests:

  ```
  import { navigate } from '@reach/router';

  ...

  onClick = () => {
     navigate('#some-link');
     // OR
     navigate('?foo=bar');
  }
  ```

  *Note the `import { navigate } from '@reach/router';` (not from Gatsby)*
- Using `window.location` redirection to get the parameters (manipulate them as you wish) and redirect the user accordingly.

Additionally, try using partial routes instead of absolute ones, since the internal navigation works better in that scenario, like:

```
navigate(/one-of-the-private-pages?param1='example')
```

Comment: Interesting I just find the problems seems to be that I was passing the full URL to navigate, and navigate only need the path for example navigate(/one-of-the-private-pages?param1='example')

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll try it  and let you know.

Comment: In my case @reach/router is working even in the case of full URL

Comment: using partial routes kept the query param! thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just solve my problem, I was using the full URL to navigate

Wrong:

```
navigate(https://example.com/one-of-the-private-pages?param1='example')
```

Correct:

```
navigate(/one-of-the-private-pages?param1='example')
```